# Cannot remove some break points in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

Sometimes Eclipse hits to break points like these..
[image]

but at this line I have not put a break point but still it keeps getting hit. Cannot skip the other break points because of this. How can I remove them.

Comment: I also suffer from the same problem :(

Comment: This usually happens because you set a breakpoint and edited the code afterwards. Sometimes Eclipse gets confused by this and loses the association between breakpoints and the sourcecode. @MrTux's solution should work fine

Answer (score 6):

I also experienced this bug.

Open the [Breakpoints](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-breakpoints_view.htm) view (Window-> Show View -> Breakpoints orif it is not listed there: Window -> Show View -> Other -> Debug -> Breakpoints). There you will get a list with all breakpoints where you can easily delete them.

Comment: thanks kinger and MrTux, But there is more going behind the scene. I'm posting it as an answer. It's only the problem not the solution though.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. I'm having classes with the same name and same package but different projects. So when I put one break point to one class eclipse places another additional hidden break point to the twin class on the same line. So to stop it we have to remove the actual break point. But this is exactly not a solution when we want break points in both the places. Also when the code get updated the mappings sometimes get scrambled. So when you click on a break point say line 4028 and when you click on it the blue dot refers to something larger number 4098.